# Why didn't Asta and Secre just ask Marx to use Memory Magic instead of taking time studying devils?

Tags: black-clover

*I just finished watching Black Clover. I haven't checked the manga yet.*

---

The title pretty  much summarizes my question. Why didn't Asta and Secre ask Marx to use Memory magic to prove that they are innocent, just like how Marx used it to know the truth from Catherine and George during the Royal Capital Assault arc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because Marx was possessed by an elf, thus it won't change peoples minds. Also even if Asta was proven innocent, one way or another, someone has to be punished for the damages(the Magic Knights who were possessed) as said by Damnatio.